# Laravel, `.png` image in public/images/product folder not displaying correctly

Tags: laravel

I am a newbie and just want to go from route->view for one image.

The image name is `Frozen_Ophelia_800x.png`

Here is my route:

```
Route::get('/products', function(){
    return view('/pages/product');
});
```

Here is my product.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <title></title>

</head>

<body>

    <h1> <img src="public/images/product/Frozen_Ophelia_800x.png"></img></h1>

</body>

</html>
```

However, when I access either `http://localhost:8000/products` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000/products` I just get a tiny little icon in the top left:
[image: tiny icon] 
I used command line to move the image to that folder from my Desktop in Ubuntu 18.04.

Here is what my project structure looks like with said image displayed:

[image: project in sublime]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access images form public folder.

(1) pass path with APP_URL

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/product/Frozen_Ophelia_800x.png">
```

(2) pass path without APP_URL

```
<img src="/images/product/Frozen_Ophelia_800x.png">
```

Comment: `<img src = "/images/product/Frozen_Ophelia_800x.png">` works!

Comment: btw do you know how to move image files into `public/images` besides using`mv` on the command line?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's an issue with the image URL being determined relative to the current page, so it would be trying to fetch:

```
http://localhost:8080/products/public/images/product/Frozen_Ophelia_800x.png
```

You can confirm that by looking at the developer console in the browser, then the network traffic.

If so, you can rewrite the `img` tag as:

```
<img src="/public/images/product/Frozen_Ophelia_800x.png">
```

Adding the `/` to the start makes the browser look for the image starting at the site root, so:

```
http://localhost:8080/public/images/product/Frozen_Ophelia_800x.png
```

Comment: it works without the` /public` not with though.  btw, do you know how to add image files to the `/public/images` folder besides using `mv` on the command line?

Comment: From the looks of it, the 3rd icon from the bottom left in should open up a file and explorer that you can use to navigate to `/var/www/html/bigStore/public` and you should be able to drag files from another file explorer window into there as needed. I’m not sure what window manager you are using there but you should be able to find help just googling for it specifically.

Comment: Follow up, I'm guessing that's Gnome 3.x, so you may be able to follow these instructions: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/files-copy.html.en

Comment: I'll check it out asap, my new job is all about vulnerability and load testing sites so it looks like I have to spend some my time there.